# Error | entroll the member admin | fabric-ca-client enroll | Amazon Managed Blockchain

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, aws-cli, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am trying to setup hyperledger fabric blockchain network using amazon managed blockchain following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-enroll-admin.html). To entroll, I have used the following command,

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u 'https://admin:#D7a22hjjh*9b9@ca.m-zzz.n-zzzz.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002' --tls.certfiles /home/ec2-user/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem -M /home/ec2-user/admin-msp
```

I got the following error,

```
Error: The URL of the fabric CA server is missing the enrollment ID and secret; found 'https://admin:#D7a22613ac75c9b9@ca.m-zzz.n-zzzz.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002' but expecting 'https://<enrollmentID>:<secret>@admin:'
```

I thought this is due to # symbol in the password. For testing purpose I remove the # symbol and tried. I got the following error.

```
Error: Failed to create keystore directory: mkdir /home/ec2-user/admin-msp: permission denied
```

when I use sudo, I am getting the following error,

```
sudo: fabric-ca-client: command not found
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What user are you logged in as? `whoami`

You should be using `ec2-user`, which has access to the `/home/ec2-user/` directory.

You can try manually creating the `admin-msp` directory before running enrolling the admin:

`cd ~ && mkdir admin-msp`

Then try running your command.

If that doesn't work, use `sudo` to create the directory and then `chown` it to be owned by `ec2-user`:

```
cd ~
sudo mkdir admin-msp
sudo chown ec2-user ~/admin-msp
```

Then try your command.

Note that you can also wrap the username/password in quotes:

`fabric-ca-client enroll -u 'https://"admin":"#D7a22hjjh*9b9"@ca.m-zzz.n-zzzz.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002' --tls.certfiles /home/ec2-user/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem -M /home/ec2-user/admin-msp`